# Limiting how many checkboxes can be checked in Powermail Typo3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, powermail

Is there a way to limit how many checkboxes can be checked in Powermail form (Typo3 v7)?

Answer (score 1):

We have to write our own validator. Typo3 add some variables within name attribute and this variable has to be read out. It looks like this:

```
name="tx_powermail_pi1[field][variable][]
```

Below an example with jquery.

```
$("input[name*='variable']").change(function(){
    var max= 3;
    if( $("input[name*='variable']:checked").length == max ){
        $("input[name*='variable']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("input[name*='variable']:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
        $("input[name*='variable']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

More info https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForDevelopers/WriteOwnValidators/Index.html